# Request data polluting the tests output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, cucumber

While I'm running my rspec-rails & cucumber-rails tests, every time a request is made the info about it gets on the log output making it hard to follow and to read.

```
Thing::SearchController
  logs data about searches
Processing by Thing::SearchController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"q"=>"thingamabob"}
  Rendered vagas/pesquisas/_empty.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered vagas/pesquisas/_facets.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered shared/_check_lang.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer_links.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (3.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 100ms (Views: 21.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Search: 67.8ms)
  another test
```

Any ideas on how can I remove it?

Here goes my Gemfile just in case:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~>3.2'
gem 'mereghost-rails_sql_views'
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jqueryui_rails'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'rabl'
gem 'exception_notification', require: 'exception_notifier'

gem 'tire'
gem 'yajl-ruby', require: 'yajl/json_gem'
gem 'tire-contrib', git: 'https://github.com/karmi/tire-contrib.git', branch: :master

gem 'devise'
gem 'uuid'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'    
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :production, :sitedev do
  gem 'therubyracer'
end

group :production, :development, :sitedev do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-cucumber'
  gem 'sprinkle'
  gem 'hitch'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'ruby-prof'
  gem 'rb-inotify'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'webmock'
end

gem 'omniauth-linkedin'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'bson_ext'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something in your code or test helpers.

```
grep -irn puts *
grep -irn Rails.logger *
```

Comment: No leads at all. Just commented out documentation lines. =/

Comment: Are you saying the Rails log is being spit out on stdout with your test output?  Or there's weird output in you log/test.log rails log?

Comment: Yep. It's coming out on my stdout. Not the entire log, just the request resolution part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the amount of detail in the log by setting `Rails.logger.level`, as described in the [Debugging Rails Applications guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels)